# IllegalFloatingActionButtonSizeException Floating action button must be a circle

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, floating-action-button

I'm getting the following error:

> IllegalFloatingActionButtonSizeException: Floating action button must
> be a circle    File "circular_notch_and_corner_clipper.dart", line 25,
> in CircularNotchedAndCorneredRectangleClipper.getClip   File
> "proxy_box.dart", line 1314, in _RenderCustomClip._updateClip   File
> "proxy_box.dart", line 1935, in RenderPhysicalShape.paint   File
> "object.dart", line 2311, in RenderObject._paintWithContext   File
> "object.dart", line 189, in PaintingContext.paintChild   File
> "box.dart", line 2826, in RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint
> File "custom_layout.dart", line 407, in
> RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311,
> in RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 189, in
> PaintingContext.paintChild   File "proxy_box.dart", line 131, in
> RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint   File "material.dart", line 555, in
> _RenderInkFeatures.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311, in RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 189, in
> PaintingContext.paintChild   File "proxy_box.dart", line 131, in
> RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint   File "object.dart", line 396, in
> PaintingContext.pushLayer   File "proxy_box.dart", line 1862, in
> RenderPhysicalModel.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311, in
> RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 189, in
> PaintingContext.paintChild   File "proxy_box.dart", line 131, in
> RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311, in
> RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 189, in
> PaintingContext.paintChild   File "proxy_box.dart", line 131, in
> RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311, in
> RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 189, in
> PaintingContext.paintChild   File "proxy_box.dart", line 131, in
> RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint   File "object.dart", line 2311, in
> RenderObject._paintWithContext   File "object.dart", line 140, in
> PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild   File "object.dart", line
> 100, in PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild   File "object.dart",
> line 978, in PipelineOwner.flushPaint   File "binding.dart", line 438,
> in RendererBinding.drawFrame   File "binding.dart", line 914, in
> WidgetsBinding.drawFrame   File "binding.dart", line 302, in
> RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback   File "binding.dart",
> line 1117, in SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback   File
> "binding.dart", line 1055, in SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame   File
> "binding.dart", line 971, in SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame   File
> "zone.dart", line 1190, in _rootRun   File "zone.dart", line 1093, in
> _CustomZone.run   File "zone.dart", line 997, in _CustomZone.runGuarded   File "hooks.dart", line 251, in _invoke   File "hooks.dart", line 209, in _drawFrame

I guess maybe it's related to the device type, but I'm not sure. Here one of the devices where I saw the error:

> brand:    "samsung", device:  "crownlte", model:  "SM-N960F"

The relevant code:

```dart
import 'package:animated_bottom_navigation_bar/animated_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';

AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    );

    CurvedAnimation curve = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.5,
        1.0,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    );

    animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: 1,
    ).animate(curve);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        _handleInternetConnection();

        Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 1),
          () {
            if (mounted) _animationController.forward();
          },
        );
      },
    );

    super.initState();
  }

...
floatingActionButton: (_currentIndex != 3 && showFAB)
            ? ScaleTransition(
                scale: animation,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  elevation: 8,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(
                    _currentIndex == 0
                        ? Icons.edit
                        : Icons.face_retouching_natural,
                    size: 36,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => _currentIndex == 0
                      ? NewStory.show(context, null)
                      : NewMood.show(context, null),
                ),
              )
            : null,
floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
            icons: allDestinations()
                .map((NavbarOption destination) => destination.icon)
                .toList(),
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            activeIndex: _currentIndex,
            gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white60,
            notchAndCornersAnimation: animation,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
            onTap: (index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Are you sure you can reproduce that issue with the latest release of animated_bottom_navigation_bar (0.3.2)?

Comment: Can we see the code for the floating action button?

Comment: @Deczaloth yes, it's happening on this last version, though it's a intermittent issue, I can't reproduce it every time

Comment: @Apps247 I've added the code

Comment: I'm getting this problem as well, I may switch to a different bottom navigation library, how did you get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following reasons might be causing the error since you mentioned that it doesn't happen every time

Maybe, the scale transition beginning from 0 ( `begin:0`) is causing the error because when it is scaled to 0 it is no longer a circle. So changing the begins to a value that is approx. 0 might solve the error i.e. `begin:0.00001`.

OR

```dart
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        _handleInternetConnection();

        Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 1),
          () {
            if (mounted) _animationController.forward();
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Solution:

1. Setting begin to  `begin:0.00001`
2. Also, it's better to use implicit animation if you want a widget to animate as soon as it is built. I've modified the code to include implicit animation instead of explicit animation ( where `forward()` must be called explicitly to animate).

Try this example (Uses null safety)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _selectedIndex == 0
          ? TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
              tween: Tween<double>(
                begin: 0.00001,
                end: 1,
              ),
              curve: Interval(
                0.5,
                1.0,
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              ),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
              builder: (_, double scaleValue, __) {
                return Transform.scale(
                    scale: scaleValue,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      elevation: 8,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.face_retouching_natural,
                        size: 36,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("hi");
                      },
                    ));
              })
          : null,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: let me know if you're still getting the error.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try that.

Comment: In my case I need the controller, since when user changes the bottom navigation I hide the action button, is it possible to do that with implicit animation?

Comment: I've updated the example code, it demonstrates the same.

Comment: I think you missed where to assign the controller inside the component, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: For what purpose do you want the controller ? What I understood when you select the option from the bottom navigation bar, for certain options you want to show the floating button and for other you don't want to show, right ?

Comment: If that's  the case then why not use the ternary operator `?` to show and hide the floating action button based on selected Index of bottom navigation bar. Also did you run the example code to see how it's working ?.

Comment: Ohh, now I got it! Yes, it's possible to do that way.

Comment: With the option of `begin:0.00001` the error still exists, I'm gonna try to implicit animation now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to run it using the latest version of the library and flutter. If it still exists, please tell me. I cannot reproduce it, so if you can do so, please give a minimal reproducible sample.

Secondly, about "I guess maybe it's related to the device type, but I'm not sure.", it is possibly not related to the device, since Flutter is cross-platform, and your code seems not to be related to native code.

Thirdly, try to use the "binary-search debug" technique. For example, try to remove all arguments from AnimatedBottomNavigationBar() and see whether it works. If so, add a few arguments and try again. If works again, add more arguments; otherwise remove some. By doing this you will see which argument causes the problem.

Comment: It still exists on the latest version. About the device specific case, I remember a setting called 'Don't keep activities' which lead me to specific errors even with Flutter, I believe it's possible (I'm gonna test with that, but can be any other thing). I'm gonna try to debug more, but as I said it happens sometimes and sometimes not (it's a public app and I see the errors with Sentry)